# Bravo SE driver for Ubuntu 19.04?

Tags: drivers, printing

Is there any special driver out there so I may use the Bravo SE CD Printer ?

The Ubuntu settings app does see the printer though.

The company, Primera does not created any driver for Linux with this printer.

Comment: Does not seem to be much luck with google, found this but the news was bad.  https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1396737-how-to-get-primera-bravo-se-auto-printer-to-work-on-ubuntu

Comment: Also found this, but uses a Windows computer or with Windows in a VM.  https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1099927.html .  It is old.

Comment: Yeah. I have seen  those. Primera have said they quit a long time ago with Linux.

Comment: It seems like the easiest way would be to use windows in VM.  Be very difficult to try to shoehorn old drivers in newer versions without breaking stuff.  Sometimes it is just better to use windows.  Win 10 is still available for free from microsoft under certain easy conditions.

Comment: Nah  LOL  I really love Ubuntu. I will find another way then.

Comment: Do not know if it can work, but maybe can use windows driver with 'wine'.